# Can you use a proxy server to retrieve a kickstart file?

Tags: centos, redhat, kickstart

I would like to access a kickstart file through a proxy.  The kickstart file is hosted on the public internet but the server doing the install can only access the internet through a proxy.

---

The following works when the kickstart file is available locally:

The sample grub.cfg in tftp that works:

```
menuentry 'Install CentOS Stream 8' {
    linuxefi centos-st8/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.ks="http://localhost/centos-st8-ks.cfg" nomodeset inst.proxy="http://192.168.0.3:3128"
    initrdefi centos-st8/initrd.img
}
```

The same kickstart file has the following:

```
text
url --url="https://public.example.com/centos-rpm-remote/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/" --proxy=http://192.168.0.3:3128/
```

---

Is there a config or setup that will also allow me to host the kickstart file somewhere accessible only through the proxy server 192.168.0.3:3128

like the following:

```
menuentry 'Install CentOS Stream 8' {
    linuxefi centos-st8/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.ks="http://public.example.com/centos-st8-ks.cfg" nomodeset inst.proxy="http://192.168.0.3:3128"
    initrdefi centos-st8/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: Your URL is only sent as cmdline to kernel, which then the install scripts pick up, so the question is if kickstart can use proxy settings. (Grub is not relevant here)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is to use "proxy" instead or "inst.proxy" even though Anaconda will complain when it starts.

```
menuentry 'Install CentOS Stream 8' {
    linuxefi centos-st8/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.ks="http://public.example.com/centos-st8-ks.cfg" nomodeset proxy="http://192.168.0.3:3128"
    initrdefi centos-st8/initrd.img
}
```